# Can pointers store values and what is the use of void pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

I know that pointers are used to store address of another memory location. The code is as follows:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    main()
    {
      int a=10;
      void *ptr=10;
      printf("%u",ptr);
    }
```

My output was: 10

Can we store values in the pointers as in the above program? What is the main use of void pointer?

Comment: `void*` is often used for containers in C due to the lack of generics.

Comment: By word "generic" Are you mean templates?

Comment: @Jashaszun In that case, void pointer can process any datatyped variables. Am I right?

Comment: @kalyan It can point to an object of any type. I'm not sure what you mean by "process". And no, it's not like templates. Templates in C++ have nothing to do with `void *` pointers, they work in a completely different (and safer) way. Seeing them as equivalent is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void *ptr=10;
```

This is not valid C, you need an explicit conversion with a cast like `(void  *) 10`.

```
printf("%u",ptr);
```

This is not valid C, you need an explicit conversion with a cast like `(unsigned int) ptr`.

Regarding the use of `void` pointers, they are generic object pointers, so you can assign a pointer value of any object pointer type to a `void *`.

Comment: I am using Turbo c compiler... My code was working perfectly without any type conversion.

Comment: @kalyan You have to enable all your compiler warnings and fix them.

Comment: @ouah: The latest version of Turbo C is 24 years old; that might not be possible ;)

Comment: @kaylan the fact that a compiler compiles your code does not mean that all compilers will accept your code

Comment: Kindly try this code in the online compiler: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php

Comment: I thought that: Here in the program, the address of value 10 is only stored in the *ptr. Whether my guess is right or wrong?

Comment: It should be mentioned that the value a pointer stores is an address. Though `void *ptr = (void *)10` made be valid syntax, it's unlikely to be a valid address unless you're working on an embedded microcontroller.

Comment: In modern C, `void *ptr = 10;` quite simply has no meaning. It is a *constraint violation* meaning that any conforming compiler must issue a diagnostic message. If that diagnostic is a warning rather than a fatal error, the standard says *nothing at all* about the behavior of the resulting program. A compiler that fails to complain about it is non-conforming; either apply options to cause your compiler to (attempt to) be conforming, or get a newer compiler. (It's *likely* that a compiler that accepts it will treat it like `void *ptr = (void*)10;`.

Answer (score 1):

> **Can we store values in the pointers as in the above program?**

The only values that should be assigned to pointer variable are:

- addresses of other objects (such as `int *foo = &x;`);
- addresses of functions (`int (*fptr)(const char *, ...) = printf;`);
- addresses of well-defined system access points (such as a communications port or an interrupt register on an embedded system);
- `NULL` (which represents a well-defined "nowhere").

You should not use pointer variables to store arbitrary values for arithmetic computation or display as you do in your example.

The declaration

```
void *ptr=10;
```

*should* have raised a diagnostic; you cannot directly assign an integer value to a pointer variable without a cast.  You might want to raise the warning level on the compiler you're using.

The statement

```
printf("%u",ptr);
```

invokes undefined behavior, since the type of the argument (`void *`) doesn't match what the conversion specifier is expecting (`unsigned int`).  It "worked" in the sense that it displayed the value you expected, but that's a matter of luck, not design.  It could just as easily have printed out a garbage value.

> **What is the main use of void pointer?**

It serves as a "generic" pointer type.  Pointers to different types are not directly assignable to each other; IOW, you can't do something like

```
char *foo;
double *bar;

foo = bar; // bzzt
```

without explicitly casting `bar` to `char *`:

```
foo = (char *) bar;
```

Similarly, if you have a function that takes a pointer parameter of one type, you can't call it with a pointer of a different type:

```
void f(char *);
...
double x;
f(&x);       // bzzt
```

The one exception to this rule is objects of `void *` type; they can be assigned without needing a cast:

```
int x;
void *foo = &x;
```

and functions that take paramters of type `void *` can accept arguments of any object pointer type:

```
void f(void *);
...
double x;
int y;

f(&x);
f(&y);
```

They're used to implement limited forms of "generic" programming (where the algorithm is the same, but the types are different).  The canonical example is the [`qsort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html) library function, which can sort arrays of any type.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the constant `10` is `int`; you are assigning an `int` to a `void *`. That's crazy, and wrong, there is absolutely no guarantee that you will get `10` when you print the value of `ptr`. You shouldn't do it. You don't know how pointer values are represented, and you don't have to. You don't care.

The use of `void` pointers is rather straightforward: it is just a way to deal with generic pointers. For example, you can implement a container of "something" by storing `void` pointers to the objects being stored. Be aware that you can't dereference it though - you need to cast it back to a valid pointer before doing so.

Also, on a side note, you should use `%p` to print pointers.

Comment: Isn't int-to-pointer (and vice versa) conversion implementation defined, not undefined?  (Undefined only in the case where the pointer can't be represented as an int)

Comment: @indiv Yes, that is correct. I didn't contradict that.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are meant to store address (memory location) of a variable. So, their size is normally the word size of the OS (like 64bit = 8 byte in 64-bit OS).

By defining the type of pointer like `int`, `char` or `void`, we restrict the use of pointer for specific data type.

1. By assigning a constant value to the pointer `void *ptr=10;`, you may have stored value but that's not the proper use pointer, and may cause segmentation fault later on. Always use pointer for storing address of variables like `void *ptr = &a;`.
2. A void pointer doesn't define the type of data that it is pointing to. We can use void pointer to store address of variable without knowing its datatype.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant directly store the value to the pointer unless and unless you refer it to something.
Pointer assignment like x=y makes y point to the same pointee as x. 
YOu can consult this for more info Visit  http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/